# How to set up main parent width of react-native-navigation drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, drawer

How to setup width of react-native navigation drawer, I can change drawer content width, But i can't change the width of main parent, I always seems white background.

```
{
initialRouteName: 'Home',
drawerPosition: 'left',
contentComponent: withUserContext(CustomDrawerContentComponent),
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
style:{
  drawer: {width:200, shadowColor: '#000000', shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 3},
    main: {paddingLeft: 3}
},
contentOptions: {
  activeTintColor: "white",
  activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
  inactiveTintColor: '#c5e6fc',
  inactiveBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    marginLeft: 10,
    },
  },
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than giving it a width of 200 just

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
```

And then get width of device by

```
const width = Dimensions.get("screen").width;
```

and then, `width: width - width/4`

Answer (score 1):

**For React Native Navigation version 6 (@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3")**

You can set required `width` value for `drawerStyle` inside `screenOptions` props of `Drawer.Navigator`.

Code Sample:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: {
          width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.25,
        },
      }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Your Component Screen Name" component={<>Your Component</>} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

As I have used `Dimensions` to get width of devices and set it as value for width. But you can set what value is required according to your needed.

Comment: Best answer... works for me although I needed more space so I did  ```width: Dimensions.get('window').width  * 0.9``` to cover *90%* of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Add one line of code and you can change width of your Drawer

```
drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
```

Don't forget to import Dimensions like this

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
```

In your code add this line as follows

```js
{
initialRouteName: 'Home',
drawerPosition: 'left',
contentComponent: withUserContext(CustomDrawerContentComponent),
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
style:{
  drawer: {width:200, shadowColor: '#000000', shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 3},
    main: {paddingLeft: 3}
},
```

You can change width accordingly like this

```
drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width/2,
```

or in any way.